# Pivots and singular cases in Gaussian Elimination

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm familiar with Gaussian Elimination from doing it using row operations to solve systems of linear equations in the past, but I've started reading a formal textbook on it, namely "Linear Algebra and its Applications" by Gilbert Strang but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding some details he was mentioning about pivot elements and singular cases. I think by explaining what I think I know about what I'm doing can in turn clue others in as to where I'm getting confused.

Basically, as far as I'm concerned, when we have a system of linear equations, like, off the top of my head and just for illustration,

$$x+y+z = 5$$
$$3x+2y-5z=20$$
$$-4x-2y+z=3$$ the vector-space interpretation is that if $x, y$ and $z$ are variables in 3 different equations with varying coefficients and numerical solutions, it can be interpreted in the column picture as $x$, $y$, and $z$ being scalars needed to produce a vector that is formed by the constants on the $RHS$ of the 3 equations in column form. So it's the required scalars for each $x, y$ and $z$ needed to create the $RHS$ vector through vector addition. Hopefully this wasn't a complete word salad.

In a row picture interpretation, it's the $x$, $y$, and $z$ value or values that specify the intersection of the three planes given by the 3 equations.

Now, in elimination, there is something I'm being told about called pivot elements, and from what I gather, they're basically when, at least when you're using Gaussian Elimination with matrices, the entry in a matrix you plan on combining with a newly operated on row to sum to 0, so that it leads you to isolating one variable to one solution, and then allows you to use back-substitution to solve the system of linear equations. For instance, if I, in the system above, subtracted 3 times equation 1 from equation 2, $3$ would be a pivot element as it causes $x=0$ in a row.

However, Strang notes that "we divide by them" in reference to pivot elements, so I think my idea of what a pivot element therefore must be false.

Proceeding, he mentions that in a singular case, a $0$ occurs in a pivot position, and elimination then must stop.

I'm not exactly sure what that means, but he gave an example of a system of linear equations that couldn't be solved by elimination:

[image]

I myself can't use elimination on this from my own experience because I can't get zeroes on the bottom left entry, middle left entry and bottom middle entry -- I end up with two zeroes in the middle left and middle middle (for lack of a better description) entry, as well as two zeros in the bottom left and bottom middle entries. This kind of screws things up when I solve it, so I can see why it's unsolvable but not what he means by "$0$ being in a pivot position" and since we apparently divide by pivot elements this causes a problem, since we cannot divide by zero.

All of this aside, I have two main questions:

- What of my pivot element interpretation is wrong, and how then is it that we divide them?
- What does he mean by "$0$ being in a pivot position" causes a singular case in, if possible, the context of how I found eliminating that example of a system of linear equations he provided impossible?

I apologize if this is a lot to answer, but I felt the questions weren't too long-winded to address to necessitate splitting each question into its own thread.

Comment: The goal of Gaussian elimination is to create a triangle form with no zeros in the diagonal. This is not possible when the matrix is singular.

Comment: @Peter What exactly prevents this from happening when it is singular?

Comment: Also, is the diagonal going from top left down to the right or bottom left up to the right?

Comment: Usually, the elimination is done in such a way that the diagonal goes from top-left to bottom-right. If the matrix is singular at some step, the diagonal-entry and every entry below are $0$, so we cannot continue.

Answer (score 1):

• So basically, when you obtain a Triangular system you have to do a process of back substitution to obtain the value of the variables.

Now, if the Pivot element is $0$ then the solution would be indeterminable. Hence, Pivot elements can't be $0$ by definition.

• While manipulating the original system   into a triangular system, we take the pivot element of the $1^{st}$ equation to make the $a_{n1} = 0$ and so on and so forth. So, while you are unable to obtain a non-zero pivot element to make  $a_{n2} = 0$ for the rest of the equations, you can't go further with Gaussian elimination.